# Geometric proof with a isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given is $\triangle ABC$ with the medians $AD$, $BE$ with $|AD|=|BE|$.
The medians intersect in $S$.

**a. Use similar triangles to show that $|AS|:|SD|=|BS|:|SE|=2:1$.**

**b. Prove that $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles triangle.**

My try:

a.  $\triangle ABC\sim\triangle EDC$, so $|AC|:|CE|=|BC|:|CD|=2:1$ (because $D$ and $E$ are the middle of the sides of the triangle).

$\triangle ABS \sim \triangle DES$, and because $|AB|:|DE|=2:1$, $|AS|:|SD|$ and $|BS|:|SE|$ must also be $2:1$.

b. I see a lot of congruent and similar triangles, and a lot of useful information, but I have no idea where to start and which information I should use for my proof. I know I should end with: $|AC|=|BC|$ or $\angle A=\angle B$. Can someone give me *a hint*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karolis Juodelė has already provided an answer, but it seems that you need more. So, I'll give you *a hint*.

You've already proved that 
$$|AS|:|SD|=|BS|:|SE|=2:1,$$
i.e.
$$|AS|=2|SD|\quad\text{and}\quad |BS|=2|SE|.$$
Now use that $|AD|=|BE|$, i.e. $|AS|+|SD|=|BS|+|SE|$ to obtain
$$3|SD|=3|SE|\quad\Rightarrow\quad |SD|=|SE|\quad \text{and}\quad |AS|=|BS|$$
from which $\triangle{SEA}\cong\triangle{SDB}$ follows.

Comment: How do you know that $|AS|=|BS|$?

Comment: @rae306: You can use $|SD|=|SE|,|AS|=2|SD|$ and $|BS|=2|SE|$.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $\triangle ABS$ is isosceles. Deduce that $\triangle AES \sim \triangle BDS$ and thus $\triangle ABD \sim \triangle ABE$. Therefore $\angle A = \angle B$.